# MariaDB MySQL Optimisation

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb, hosting, vps

I stuck a bit with setting the best performance of MariaDB on my VPS. I have:
6 cores; 16GB RAM; 300GB SSD; CloudLinux; LiteSpeed

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.2.13-MariaDB-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/lib/mysql/dev.whitespot.co.err(611K)
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/dev.whitespot.co.err exists
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/dev.whitespot.co.err is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/dev.whitespot.co.err is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/dev.whitespot.co.err is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/sqlhost.err contains 4467 warning(s).
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/sqlhost.err contains 164 error(s).
[--] 8 start(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/dev.whitespot.co.err
[--] 1) 2018-02-14  3:17:43 140627065792640 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2018-02-14  3:08:56 140369082124416 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2018-02-14  3:04:17 140342812088448 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 2018-02-14  2:27:29 139698717120640 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 2018-02-14  2:27:05 140353362925696 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 2018-02-14  0:59:46 140394864134272 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 2018-02-14  0:58:53 140612241397888 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 8) 2018-02-14  0:40:07 140392565569664 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7 shutdown(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/sqlhostname.err
[--] 1) 2018-02-14  3:17:39 140368255764224 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2018-02-14  3:08:52 140342016706304 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 2018-02-14  3:04:13 139688655320832 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 2018-02-14  2:27:26 140353156269824 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 2018-02-14  2:26:59 140384804599552 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 2018-02-14  0:59:42 140611259844352 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 2018-02-14  0:58:49 140391611623168 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE 
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 2G (Tables: 4460)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 1G (Tables: 1872)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[!!] User 'netdata@localhost' has no password set.
[!!] User 'jb9363_user@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[!!] User 'robak@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[!!] User 'robak_alexadam@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[!!] User 'robak_francesco@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[!!] User 'robak_g@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[!!] User 'robak_pro@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[!!] User 'robak_tom@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[--] There are 612 basic passwords in the list.

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 8h 12m 49s (4M q [162.139 qps], 51K conn, TX: 41G, RX: 1G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 97% / 3%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 15.7G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 9.8G
[--] Other process memory: 1.5G
[--] Total buffers: 8.4G global + 4.7M per thread (300 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 8.5G (54.58% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 9.8G (62.60% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[!!] Slow queries: 36% (1M/4M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 8% (24/300)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.13%  (66/51527)
[!!] Query cache is disabled
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (24 temp sorts / 563K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 10333
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 69% (195K on disk / 282K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (24 created / 51K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 98% (7K open / 7K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 38% (9K/25K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (2M immediate / 2M locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 6 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.2.13-MariaDB-log)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 31.3% (84M used / 268M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 256.0M/295.8M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.9% (34M cached / 34K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 12.9% (112K cached / 97K writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 8.0G/1.6G
[OK] InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 1.0G * 2/8.0G should be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 64 for 8 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.99% (205255768 hits/ 205283702 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 77.83% (185463 hits/ 238296 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 52833 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[!!] Aria pagecache hit rate: 93.9% (2M cached / 181K reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server.

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/sqlhostname.err file
    Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/sqlhostname.err file
    Set up a Password for user with the following SQL statement ( SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'SpecificDNSorIp' = PASSWORD('secure_password'); )
    Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (>= 8M)
    join_buffer_size (> 2.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    tmp_table_size (> 64M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 64M)
```

I've installed some monitoring tool for SQL. This software emails me every hour about slow queries. Log file is now 500mb... log created in 12h :/

I run on this VPS only WordPress websites via LiteSpeed + LS Cache. Please help me optimise this a bit. I'm not saying websites are slow, but I reckon better MySQL optimisation will be better for whole server performance and maybe even speed up wordpress installations a bit.

Comment: First. This is a question for https://dba.stackexchange.com/ .  Second, your question is like saying: My truck goes slowly up hill, help me make it faster.  What kind of truck? What are you hauling? What hill (Loveland Pass in Colorado, or a freeway onramp in Iowa)? How fast do you need to go? How fast are you going?    Please read this, especially the section on performance.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  In the meantime, post a job opening saying "Clairvoyant MySQL Administrator Help Wanted. If you qualify you already know where to apply."  (Sorry for the snark....)

Comment: first question here buddy... be nice ok?

Comment: Please post complete test results from Linux prompt for the following: 
    A)  ulimit -a         so we can see your OS limits, it will be a short list
    B) iostat             when busy so we can see SSD writes per second. 
    These two posted results will guide in setting some my.cnf/ini settings.
I will be kind to you and remember my first post.  Which was respectfully answered.

Comment: for B) above, use 'iostat -x' to IOPS reporting.  And identify your SSD Device, please.

Comment: What is the value of `long_query_time`?

Comment: Summarize the slowlog using `pt-query-digest` or `mysqldumpslow -s t`.  Then let's look at the first few (the worst) queries.  You cannot "tune your way out of performance problems".  It is usually indexing or query formulation that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please post one of the hourly slow query e-mails so we can see your available report and assist.

Things you can do now in your my.cnf/ini [mysqld] section to improve situation,

```
max_connections=50  # from 300 to reduce RAM footprint
change next 4 on one day, please   shutdown/restart
#sort_buffer_size=val  # lead with # to use default
#read_buffer_size=val  # lead with # to use default
#read_rnd_buffer_size=val  # lead with # to use default
#join_buffer_size=val  # lead with # to use default
thread_cache_size=50  # from ? to reduce threads_created
innodb_thread_concurrency=8  # from 0 to enable
innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1024 to avoid overloading page_cleaners
innodb_page_cleaners=64  # from def for autolimit to be = innodb_buffer_pool_instances
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=ON  # to prepare for WARM IBPool
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=ON  # to WARM the innodb_buffer_pool
innodb_flush_neighbors=0  # should be OFF when using SSD, there is not latency
```

Good luck, and you will not be able to vote on OR accept anything until your reputation is around 15.  In your case, limit changes to one per day so you can see the effects with monitoring to appreciate what this analysis and implementation does for you.

Use of MySQLCalculator.com will be 2 valuable minutes spent looking at RAM footprint before and after changes.